# How to require a node package that wants to be a module, without type: module

Tags: node.js, npm, require, package.json

I need to import a module to my project.

When I do `const gifsicle = require('gifsicle');` it tells me:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
```

When I try to do import, it says

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Other threads say to fix this I have to add `"type": "module"` to my package.json

But doing so gives me this error:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
```

How do I load in an ES module package into my current non-module package which uses require?

Comment: Read https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c

Comment: so I'm just forced to upgrade my entire project to a format i dont like to use this one module

Comment: Yes, unless `gifsicle` has an older version available that supports CJS.

Comment: `gifsicle@5` does support ESM, however it seems to be unmaintained. I strongly encourage you to move to ESM. ESM is the spec used in browsers. ESM would allow you to use other ESM modules and you can continue using CJS modules.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all add "type":"commonjs" to package.json.
2. Downgrade your package version. If you are using let suppose version 8.0.0 then install older version like npm i package-name@7.1.0.
   That's all now enjoy coding...